# Run ef migrations script on separate projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, entity-framework-migrations

I have a .NET Core 3.1 Web App using Entity Framework. 
The WebApp is in a project Command.Api, whereas the EF with the DBContext classes in another project Command.Core.

I want to create the migration script by running command

```
dotnet ef migrations script
```

Unfortunately I get the error

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation.  ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This happens because the DBContext classes are in separate project than program.cs.
When DBContext classes are in the same project with program.cs, script works properly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: While running the migration command have you selected the `Command.Core` project?

Comment: I run the command in the same folder or if I run the command from solution folder, I specify project's name. in both cases the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we must specify startup project

```
dotnet ef migrations script --project Command.Core --startup-project Command.Api
```